# Adding multiple widgets to an ios TableView row?

Tags: ios, tableview

ios Noob here. I have an iOS `TableView` which needs to have a few items in each row: A `UILabel` for asking a question, Yes button, No button, and a slider to answer "rate between 1 and 5". The slider won't actually show on every question only when the question deals with a rating.

What's the best way to accomplish adding all the "widgets" to the `TableView row`? Progmatically or through storyboards? Also, if I use `storyboards`, how would I go about hiding the rating bar and then showing it again when needed?

UPDATED WITH CODE SNIPPET

```
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *ObjQuestions;
    ...

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            // Configure the cell...
            OBJ_Question *q1 = [self.ObjQuestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = q1.QuestionText;          

            // need to access second and third Label widgets from storyboard here
            // as well as show/hide NSSlider
            return cell;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subclass `UITableviewCell` and add your custom items to the content view of the `UITableViewCell`. Use your custometableview cell in your `UITableView` datasource & delegate method. If you need more info than this, let me know and I can give you a sample code

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm doing it that way now but not clear how I reference the additional widgets in the TableView row. Right now, I'm setting the text of the row by way of cell.textLabel.text = @"foo". I'm not clear where cell.textLabel object comes from. I'm guessing it's a automatic default for the TableView row. How do I reference cell.textLabel2.text or cell.NSSlider.value, etc, etc once I've added them to the storyboard? Do i use the view Tag somehow?

Comment: Yes, textLabel is a property of UITableviewCell.Now coming to your question, every cell in a UITableview is reference by something called  index path. An indexpath is used to reference a cell in which section and which row in that section.You should have a data source which supplies the data to UITableview cell like cell.textLabel.text = [Datasource objectAtIndex:[indexpath row]]. Are you using storyboard for your project or normal XIB files?

Comment: I added to the code snippet to show my backing array for the tableview. I left it out for brevity, but perhaps confused the issue. I am using storyboards for the project and have set the Identifier for the Table View Cell to "Cell". Not sure how to identify other widgets I place in that "Cell". I don't see a place to give the other widgets identifiers so that must not be the way to do it.

Comment: Check this link. I have added sample code and see whether it helps. I have used storyboard and tags in my code https://github.com/slysid/iOS/tree/master/Widget. I have developed in Xcode 4

Comment: That's awesome! Just what I needed. The part I was mising was the view tag bits:  label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];  You've also used multiple rows as noted by Abizern, below, to handle displaying a slider or yes/no question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Storyboards you can create two types of cells, one with the slider, and one without. All you need to do then is to load the correct cell depending on your data for that row.

It's easier than trying to hide and show the slider.

Comment: Nice! I do that sort of thing in Android and was also something I was wondering about.